# Rewrite parameter url to normal url but it should get original url parameters after redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Original URL:
https://www.example.com/all_users/user.php?id=1&subtype=p

Expected URL:
https://www.example.com/user/john-doe.html

I tried using following rule, it redirects to expected URL but I can't use parameters (id and subtype) with new URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id\=1&subtype\=p$
RewriteRule ^all_users/user\.php$ https://www.example.com/user/john-doe.html? [R=301,L]
```

How can I use parameter values with new URL.

Example:

After redirect, new URL will be https://www.example.com/user/john-doe.html
Then I should able to get original parameters value with new URL.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$type = $_GET['subtype'];
```

Comment: "After redirect" - What URL are you actually linking to?

Comment: @MrWhite This is my old URL https://www.example.com/all_users/user.php?id=1&subtype=p and this will be new URL https://www.example.com/user/john-doe.html

Comment: Ok, so you are linking to the new URL and you just need to redirect the old URLs for SEO benefit?

Comment: @MrWhite Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following htaccess rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/all_users/user\.php\?id=\d+&subtype=p\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  user/john-doe.html? [R=301,L]
##Internal rewrite from here..
RewriteRule ^user/john-doe\.html/?$  all_users/user.php?id=1&subtype=p [QSA,NC,L]
```